# C2HS Pointer Type Correspondences

Tags: pointers, haskell, ffi, c2hs

I have some conceptual questions about how C2HS generates type correspondences from `{#pointer …}` declarations. First, let `~` denote a type correspondence operator between C types and Haskell types. Then is it correct to say that

```
{#pointer *CTypeName as HaskellName newtype#}
```

generates the correspondence `*CTypeName ~ HaskellName`, while

```
{#pointer *CTypeName as HaskellName foreign newtype#}
```

generates the correspondence `*CTypeName ~ (Ptr HaskellName)`? (If so, does this imply in the latter case that `CTypeName ~ HaskellName` also?)

This is despite the fact that C2HS generates slightly different type definitions for each of the different declarations:

```
-- {#pointer *CTypeName as HaskellName newtype#}
data HaskellName = HaskellName (Ptr HaskellName)

-- {#pointer *CTypeName as HaskellName foreign newtype#}
data HaskellName = HaskellName (ForeignPtr HaskellName)
```

The `~` correspondences I mentioned above are somehow enforced by GHC/C2HS in the background, and they are only used to make `foreign import …` FFI declarations more type safe. If instead of writing `{#pointer ...}` declarations, we wrote instead their generated `data HaskellName ..` declarations as above (i.e., not using C2HS), then the C-to-Haskell type associations wouldn't be enforced by GHC natively (I'm assuming).

Finally, if we delete the `*` character in the `{#pointer …}` declarations above, then instead of us having type correspondences between  `*CTypeName ~ HaskellName` and  `*CTypeName ~ (Ptr HaskellName)`, we would have type correspondences between `CTypeName ~ HaskellName` and `CTypeName ~ (Ptr HaskellName)`.

Is all of my understanding correct?